# I want to get all the list of files in same form as they are saved from local storage(Hardisk space)/server from the particular path

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I want to display list of all files(.jpg,.mp3,.psd,.tiff etc) from local storage(hard disk space) and the path of local storage gets generated when SQL query gets fired for eg. I have fields `folder_name`, `Subfolder_name` and `Id`.

So suppose Query: `Select Folder_name,Subfolder_name From Table where Id = 101;`
suppose I get output `Folder_name=Users,Subfolder_name = Public`. Now this value must gets passed in the path for eg: `Path =C:\Users\Public\`. And from this Path I want to display all the files in the same form as they are saved.

In my current implementation I m getting list of files in base64 form.But i want in the Same form as they are saved.for eg. if file is in jpg want to display list of jpg's file.

I m getting list of files in base64 form .

```
  public List<Image> GetImagesBySourceKey(string ID)
        {
            List<Image> images = new List<Image>();


            string sqlQuery = "select folder_name,Subfolder_name from Table where Id= '" +
                              Id+ "'";

            foreach (DataRow dataRow in ExecuteQuery(sqlQuery))
            {                
                images.Add(new Models.Image()
                {
                    folder_name= dataRow["folder_name"].ToString(),
                    Subfolder_name = dataRow["Subfolder_name"].ToString()

                });
                DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\\Users\\bhagyeshc\\source\\repos\\abcd\\abcd\\" +
                                                    images[0].FileName + "\\" + Subfolder_name);
                FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.*"); //Getting  files

                foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
                {
                    Image image = new Image();
                    var path = Path.Combine("~\\" + images[0].FileName + "\\" + Subfolder_name+ "\\" + file.Name);
                    image.Code = ImageBase64(path);
                    images.Add(image);
                }


            }

            return images;

        }

        private string ImageBase64(string path)
        {

            path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path);
            var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(path);
            var contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(contents);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            return base64String;

        }
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Please revise to make it more clear what you're trying to achieve and explain explicitly what problems you're having. If you're getting any exceptions, provide those along with the relevant stack traces. FWIW, bear in mind that for security reasons, filesystem access on the client-side is *extremely* limited. You basically can only pop a file upload dialog, allowing a user to specify one or more files, not folders, and certainly not direct access to any part of the filesystem to list files.

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\"+Folder_name+"\"+SubFolder_name");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.jpg"); //Getting Text files
string str = "";
foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
{
str = str + ","+file.Name;

}
```

str will return  all files under this folder

Comment: Hello thank you so much .But From this i will get base64 string,actually i wanted to get the List of files in same form as they are saved.

Comment: Thank u so much .str will return file names only.I want to display the files in the same form as they are saved. for eg. if file is .jpg. i want to diplay .jpg image.